# Dos eventos click se hacen al mismo tiempo

Tags: html, angular

Tengo un evento `click` en una card y dentro de esa card tengo un botón con otro evento `click` distinto, cuando presiono el botón se ejecuta el de la card y el del botón, lo que quiero es que cuando presiono el del botón solo se ejecute ese. Les dejo una imagen y el código del `html`.

```
    <mat-card *ngFor="let current of dataSource" fxFlex="30" (click)="viewClient(current.id)">
                <div class="title" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between center">
                    <div fxLayoutAlign="start center">
                        <span>{{current.orderNumber}}.-</span>
                        <img mat-card-avatar src="{{current.avatar}}">
                        <span>{{current.companyName}}</span>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <button (click)="change(current.id)" mat-mini-fab
                            aria-label="Example icon button with a border_color icon">
                            <mat-icon>child_care</mat-icon>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
    </mat-card>
```

Comment: Intenta con `(click)="change(current.id); $event.stopPropagation()"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hace poco tuve el mismo problema, la solución la encontré en el mismo SO; lo que se hace es usar el método `event.stopPropagation()`.

```
<button (click)="change(current.id),$event.stopPropagation()" mat-mini-fab
        aria-label="Example icon button with a border_color icon">
     <mat-icon>child_care</mat-icon>
</button>
```

Lo que hace básicamente este método es evitar que se siga propagando el evento (click en este caso), de tal modo que no afectará a los demás eventos ni procesos.

Referencias útiles:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61548656/clicking-buttons-inside-angular-materials-card-triggers-the-click-event-of-the